# Create a matrix out of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am very new to R and script writing in general. Please be patient if this is a very basic question. My search for a solution has not been successful.

```
date.depature <- c("2016.06.16", "2016.11.16", "2017.01.05", "2017.01.12", "2017.02.25")
airport.departure <- c("CDG", "QNY", "QXO", "CDG", "QNY")
airport.arrival <- c("SYD", "CDG", "QNY", "SYD", "QXO")
amount <- c("1", "3", "1", "10", "5")
df <- data.frame(date.depature, airport.departure, airport.arrival, amount)
```

I want to change the df to a matrix which has the airport.departure as rows and the airport.arrival as columns with the cumulated amount for a given month/years in the cells of the matrix.

Comment: Your title is bad for my OCD :)

Comment: Sorry. I did not notice it. Now it gives me slight pain too...

Comment: hehehe, you don't expect it to be such a big deal until you 'see' it

Comment: Good thing it´s possible here to change the title. It would be mean to trigger OCDs all over the world. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `xtabs`, i.e.

```
xtabs(amount ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df)
```

which gives,

> ```
>               airport.departure
> airport.arrival CDG QNY QXO
>             CDG   0   3   0
>             QNY   0   0   1
>             QXO   0   5   0
>             SYD  11   0   0
> ```

**P.S**

As @Andre Elrico mentions, for some reason you declared your `amount` variable as a string. You need to convert to integer prior to calculating the sums

*Proposed Solution:*

```
xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df)
```

Comment: since amount is string: `xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df)`

Comment: if you further want to work on this: consider using `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs( ... ))`

Comment: The "for some reason" is that I barely what I am doing. So it just happend without thinking. I changed it in the real dataframe. 

I will look into it. Thank you for the advice & help from both of you.

Answer (score 0):

using dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(month.departure =substr(date.depature, 1, 7)) %>%
  group_by(airport.departure, airport.arrival, month.departure) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(as.numeric(as.character(amount))))
```

- mutate adds a column that gives the month/year (without the date, because you asked to group by month)
- group_by says you want to see statistics grouped according to these variables
- summarize computes the statistic you're looking for, in this case the total amount per 'group.' The `as.numeric(as.character())` is included because 'amount' started as a factor type, which can't be summed [the `as.character()` is needed because as.numeric would have unexpected behavior if called directly on the factor]. `total =` gives an arbitrary column name to include in the output table; you could leave it out and this will still work.
- the %>% is used to pipe output from one command as input to the next command in dplyr

Output:

[image: output table]

(format of output table is different than you described, but it contains all the info you're looking for. and dplyr is a great package to start learning for this sort of data manipulation!)