# Filter out rows/columns which hold less 10% of the results in a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a matrix build from data in a similar structure:

```
airport.departure <- c("CDG", "QNY", "QXO", "CDG", "QNY")
airport.arrival <- c("SYD", "CDG", "QNY", "SYD", "QXO")
amount <- c(1, 3, 1, 10, 5)

df <- data.frame(airport.departure, airport.arrival, amount)
xtabs(amount ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure
```

That results in like here:

```
               airport.departure
airport.arrival CDG QNY QXO
            CDG   0   3   0
            QNY   0   0   1
            QXO   0   5   0
            SYD  11   0   0
```

Now I need to filter out rows/columns which contain a very low amount of the values. Only rows/columns which contain more than 10% of the total data should be shown.

Comment: That code looks familiar :) Can you please post what you have tried as well?

Comment: your question should always contain the **desired result**. Also read my comment on the [very familiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53378223/6852937). Then you will google: `"remove columns rows based on condition r"`.

Comment: Please, Confusulum, please do some research about R. There are several really good tutorials on R (google/bing/[rseek](https://rseek.org/) are your friends) that demonstrate selecting rows or columns based on some condition. Even if you choose to not use google or bing, SO has a lot of questions that likely contain what you are looking for (one such search on SO: [`[r] matrix filter column`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+matrix+filter+column)). Regardless, please search before you ask, you'll often get what you need much faster. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Hello again @Sotos!
The advices of you other two guys have not helped me sadly.

I have researched and am trying to figure the prerequisits out that need to be fullfilled before I can do the conversion that I want, but R is a language that I don't understand. 
I would not have asked if time wasn't an issue. I understand that this kind of posts annoy you, though. Sorry for wasting your time and have nice evening.